# Pivot and merge columns in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a table with the following columns

```
Col1(bigint) | Col2(datetime)| Col3(nvarchar(100))| Col4(xml)
```

The 4th column is a xml which looks like following, it may contain any number of fields

```
<Fields>
  <Field1>10</Field1>
  <Field2>11</Field2>
  <Field3>10</Field3>
  <Field4>11</Field4>
</Fields>
```

I need to query multiple rows from the table. I am creating a stored procedure which gets 2 parameters

Parameter1: `@query` (type of `xml`)

```
<Rowset> 
   <Row> 
     <Col1>20140510123205321</Col1> 
     <Col2>2014-05-14T13:01:03.1426856+05:30</Col2> 
     <Col3>Source1</Col3> 
   </Row> 
   <Row> 
     <Col1>20140510123205322</Col1> 
     <Col2>2014-05-14T13:01:03.1426856+05:30</Col2> 
     <Col3>Source2</Col3> 
   </Row> 
</Rowset>
```

Parameter2: `@Fields` (type of string comma separated)

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
```

I am expecting a output in the following format

```
Col1      |   Col2   |  Col3 | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2014051092|2014-05-14|Source1|   10   |   21   |  12    |   43 
2014051093|2014-05-14|Source1|   11   |   22   |  23    |   53
```

I have created a table from the first parameter in the stored procedure.

```
INSERT INTO #TempPricing                     
 (                                                                              
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3                                                  
 )                                                                              
SELECT                                                                               
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3                               
    FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/Rowset/Row', 2)                                                                                 
 WITH                                                                               
 (                                                         
    Col1 bigint,
    Col2 datetime,
    Col3 varchar(50)      
 )
```

How can I pivot the second parameter after splitting, merge it with the table above and fetch the data?

**EDIT**
The output can also be the following format

```
Col1      |   Col2   |  Col3 | Fields 
--------------------------------------
2014051092|2014-05-14|Source1|<Fields><Field1>10</Field1><Field1>11</Field1></Fields>
2014051093|2014-05-14|Source1|<Fields><Field1>20</Field1><Field1>21</Field1></Fields>
```

so any of the above formats will work

Comment: I was able to achieve the above by using directives from the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681510/fetch-queried-xml-nodes-from-a-column-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the below script it may help you.

```
declare @String varchar(max), @Result varchar(max)

select @String= COALESCE(@String+',', '')+ QUOTENAME(Col1) 
FROM (
select distinct Col1 from TableA A Inner Join dbo.Tab C VS on A.AttributeID =VS.AttributeId)AS B
set @Result ='
with pivotData AS
(
select distinct P.Col1, PA.col1,A.Col1,PA.col2 from Tab3 PA join Attribute A
on A.AttributeID=PA.AttributeID join Product P on P.ProductId=PA.ProductId
)
select Col1, Col2,
'+@String+' from pivotData
pivot(
Max(col2) for
Col1in('+@String+')
)as PR order by col3 desc'

exec (@Result)
```