# Fetch queried xml nodes from a column in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a table with 2 columns first is an integer column with primary keys and the second is a xml column with data.

The data column contains the xml as follows

```
<Fields>
    <Field1>10</Field1>
    <Field2>11</Field2>
    <Field3>10</Field3>
    <Field4>11</Field4>
</Fields>
```

The number of fields are not fixed and may vary in each row. I want to write a stored procedure which accepts 2 parameters the comma separated primary keys and comma separated string. So my 2 parameters will be

```
32,54,63,653
Field1,Field2
```

The sp will return a datatable with the following

```
32 | <Fields><Field1>10</Field1><Field2>11</Field2></Fields>
54 | <Fields><Field1>50</Field1><Field2>62</Field2></Fields>
63 | <Fields><Field1>32</Field1><Field2>542</Field2></Fields>
653| <Fields><Field1>15</Field1><Field2>21</Field2></Fields>
```

I am facing problems in selecting only the required nodes from the xmls in the data column.

**Edit**

I have tried the following

```
select PricingXML.query('/Fields/Field1') from T_SMPricingData
```

But I want the above for many fields not only the field1

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? "I am facing problems in selecting only the required nodes from the xmls in the data column." It's one thing to insert the data, it's something else to extract it. Is your database filestream enabled? That's a requirement from what I remember from mcsa exams..

Comment: The table in the DB contains many fields in the xml column but I want to select only the fields mentioned in the parameter2. So I need to extract only that data and return it.

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: I split the parameters but I dont know how to extract only the nodes which I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a split string function of your choice something like this.

```sql
create function dbo.SplitString
(
  @List nvarchar(max),
  @Delimiter nvarchar(255)
)
returns table
with schemabinding
as
return 
(  
  select Item = T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
  from (
       select convert(xml, N'<N>' + replace((select @List for xml path('')), @delimiter, N'</N><N>') + N'</N>').query('.')
       ) as T1(X)
    cross apply T1.X.nodes('N') as T2(X)
);
```

Use that in a stored procedure like this.

```sql
create procedure GetPricing
  @IDs nvarchar(max),
  @Nodes nvarchar(max)

as
select T.ID,
       (
       select F.X.query('.')
       from T.PricingXML.nodes('/Fields/*') as F(X)
         inner join dbo.SplitString(@Nodes, ',') as N
           on F.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') = N.Item
       for xml path(''), root('Fields'), type
       ) as PricingXML
from dbo.T_SMPricingData as T
  inner join dbo.SplitString(@IDs, ',') as N
    on T.ID = cast(N.Item as int)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2fb51/1)

Comment: The procedure is great. Many of the keywords used are new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  Roles
from
  MyTable
where
  Roles.value('(/root/role)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'StringToSearchFor'
```

you may find more sample code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server.aspx) and [here](http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/125/querying-xml-fields-using-t-sql).

Also, you may be interested in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae0d5/13) that shows how to look in xml columns.

I'm used to see XML in the following way:

```
<School>
  <Class>Geography</Class>
  <Class>Mathematics</Class>
  <Class>Programming</Class>
  <teacher>Mrs Crabaple</Teacher>
</School>
```

field1, field2 are pretty meaningless. Give them meanings.

Comment: Thanks for the directions but I am still stuck. The query above will search for values inside the xml tags. I actually want to search for xml tags not the values inside.